# Sum of the Reciprocal of the Difference of Two Squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a closed-form expression for the sum:

$$
\sum \limits_{i=2}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2-1}
$$

Comment: What is a closed-form expression? +1 by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint
$$
\frac{1}{i^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{i-1}-\frac{1}{i+1}\right)
$$
Now use [telescopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It had actually occurred to me to express it as partial fractions, but after I did that I was stuck because I did not know about "telescopy", and the harmonic series (1/i) seemed nasty to deal with, so I assumed that this would be too. Clearly, I was wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dara You can accept this answer (by clicking checkbox under votes conunt) if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a closed form for the series

$$ -\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {1+2\,n}{ \left( n+1 \right) n}} + \frac{3}{4} \,. $$